# DRUPAL: tags for CCK fields?

Tags: drupal

can I add tags to specific CCK Fields such as FileField, ImageFIeld or VideoField ?
And successively filter them according to the tag ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that. You need to create another node type, add CCKs to it and then tag it using Taxonomy. And then refer this new node to first one.